# Ubuntu wireless got disconnected when far from router

Tags: 14.04, wireless, dual-boot

I finally did install Ubuntu 14.04 on my Asus notebook. Now, my laptop is on dual-boot Windows7 and Ubuntu. All is working well, however, after getting the updates `sudo apt-get update` and setting up the wireless connection, I noticed something very strange and annoying: as my laptop is connected, if I try to move through the rooms I lose the Internet signal.

If I boot to Windows, at the same distance, I get the internet signal very well. In summary :

- From 2 m off the router : Ubuntu and W7 both receives well
- From 8 m or more off the router:   W7 receives normally and Ubuntu receives nothing and gets disconnected.

`lspci -nn -d 14e4:`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux azzed-Ubu 3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`iwconfig`

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"ZTE"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: 00:15:EB:F6:2F:DC   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Comment: bcm...? Please add the complete driver/module name to your question.

Comment: First, thank you for helping me. Here is the full name: Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (prorietary).Please don't hesitate to ask me more details If you wish

Comment: proprietary source repository? Isn't that a contrary in itself? In the future, please use the edit function to add details to your question.

Comment: I am new on Ubuntu. I tried other things to try to recover the Wifi signal. I tried to remove the default driver and installing afterwards linux-firmware-nonfree and load the b43 module. But nothing happened, as my Wifi signal is still very poor. After I tried to update to kernel 3.17 but things get worse as my Wifi router ain't shown anymore, so I have to uninstall it i think. Any suggestions if you can.

Comment: I've juste removed the 3.17 version and now I'm on the 3.13 version. Wifi signal is back now but still very very poor unfortunately. Any suggestions please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Use the above resource wisely and follow it to the letter (which means: find a cable and remove the driver you have) and then go to the link above and *very carefully* follow the instructions over there.  If something is out of the ordinary in the steps you take there, drop a comment here @Fabby

Comment: Thank you for your help. To be honest I don't know exactly what to do, I installed the driver wireless for BCM43142 but got confused after reading the Readme.txt. I tried also the build-dep linux but nothing happened. I still have very poor wifi signal strenght (always 2 bars lesser than windows).

Comment: @Fabby - I did try almost all the instructions, I used the following : sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source && install bcmwl-kernel-source. Nothing changed. I removed the same kernel and tried filmaware-b43-installer && fwcutter and blacklister b43xx. nothing changed. I tried other stuff, but always the same. I dont know my pbm is a bit odd, all is working well but the signal strength is never more than 2 bars near the router. I have a BCM3142 / driver : wl.

Comment: what's the output of `lspci -nn -d 14e4:`

Comment: @Fabby I put the output above on the main question.

Comment: Nepto.py: Upvoted your question and getting some expert help...  @Chili555: care to have a look?

Comment: @Nepto.py Is the performance the same, better or worse with N speeds turned off in the router?

Comment: I cant find this N speeds, I scanned all the page but I didn't find it. Is it related to the beacon Interval (ms) [20 - 1000]?